# Удалить маленькую полоску в CSS

Tags: css, css-grid, градиент

Прошу о помощи, так как перепробовал уже все, что мог родить мой несведущий в CSS мозг. Сайт art.auditerra.ru. Через каждые два ряда вот эта полоска из-за того, что два градиента наезжают друг на друга на 1px. https://www.screencast.com/t/LbTxHYqwB0uB

Градиент задан для класса .col-xs-12:

```
.col-xs-12 {
    background: linear-gradient(90deg, 
rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 0%, rgba(150, 150, 150, 0.51) 34.38%, rgba(116, 116, 116, 0.666885) 51.04%, rgba(150, 150, 150, 0.52) 66.15%,
    rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 100%) !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Алекс,

Задача ясна, удалить полоску (из вашего описания). Но не понятно в чем ваша трудность. Вы не упомянули какого решения вы ждете
Что требуется откорректировать градиент?

Градиенты с прозрачностью наезжают друг на друга.

- Если вы хотите этого избежать, откорректируйте отступы (сейчас они у
  вас абсолютные) чтобы не наезжали друг на друга. [image: абсолютные значения]
- Либо создайте градиент без прозрачности.

```css
    .col-xs-12 {
        background: linear-gradient(90deg, 
           rgb(204, 204, 204) 0%, 
           rgb(180, 180, 180) 34.38%, 
           rgb(147, 147, 147) 51.04%, 
           rgb(147, 147, 147) 66.15%, 
           rgb(204, 204, 204) 100%) !important;
    }
```

[image: решение]

- пересмотреть подачу, например в сторону flex.
- использовать img как background
- и т.д.

Comment: Большое спасибо, вы сильно помогли и расширили мой багаж знаний!